# If else not working inside of Firebase snapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've written the following code to check if two users are inside of a room:

```js
useEffect(() => {
        var chatroom = db.collection('test').where("Users", "array-contains", `${selectedUser}`);

        chatroom.get().then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                if (doc.data().Users.includes(username) && doc.data().Users.includes(selectedUser)) {
                    console.log("Found match");

                    ...etc...

                    setMessages(objects);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Didn't find a valid chat");
                    setMessages([]);
                }

                console.log("???");

            })
        });
    }, [username, selectedUser]);
```

It works correctly when the if condition is successful however, if the condition is false then the else won't execute and even the console.log("???") is never run. I'm not sure what could be causing this.

Edit: I found a work around by adding a boolean to represent whether or not a match was found. Code outside of the snapshot still runs so I just moved stuff over there.

Edit2: Actually this doesn't work since I forgot javascript will just run the code at the bottom before the data is retrieved.

Comment: Maybe, if you try instead of 'else', write another if-statement.
if( !doc.data().Users.includes(username) && !doc.data().Users.includes(selectedUser) ) {
    //your code
}

Comment: @L.Papadopoulos Tried that and unfortunately it didn't work. Is it possible to await the entire snapshot and then my code after the chatroom.get() won't execute till it's done?

Comment: Does it throw any error?

Comment: @L.Papadopoulos No errors nothing. Can't seem to figure out what on earth is going on here.

Comment: @L.Papadopoulos Ok so I managed to solve the problem using the idea mentioned in edit #1 coupled with async/await, I just wrapped it in an asynchronous function and then await the firebase query. Then I check a boolean found to see if I got it or not.

Comment: Hi @Craig great to hear that you could find out the solution! Please, consider adding your solution as answer, so in case similar cases occur or any other members access this question, it has a solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publishing this as Community Wiki answer, based in the thread of comments of the question. Feel free to update and change it with more details.

As informed by @Craig, the solution was to follow the idea from the first edit. By using a couple of coupled with `async` and `await`, it's possible to wrap the snapshot in an asynchronous function and then `await` the Firebase query. Once the data is returned, it's possible to check if boolean is found, to confirm if a match was found.